# UICollectionView performBatchUpdates: asserts unexpectedly if view needs layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

If I call `-[UICollectionView performBatchUpdates:]` from inside `viewWillAppear:`, inside `viewDidAppear:`, between these methods, or anytime the collection view has not been laid out by the greater UIView view hierarchy, the collection view will assert with:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>       reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections 
>       contained in the collection view after the update (X) must be equal to the number 
>       of sections contained in the collection view before the update (X), plus or minus 
>       the number of sections inserted or deleted (X inserted, 0 deleted).'

Where "X" is whatever number of items I've inserted.  I've confirmed that the data source is being updated properly and the index paths in the update are correct.

How could the collection view state become consistent with the data source, when the data source was just updated immediately before calling `performBatchUpdates:`?  It seems something is unexpectedly triggering a reloadData.

Answer (score 12):

UICollectionView seems to have special behavior (a bug?): if it needs layout, then `performBatchUpdates:` effectively acts as a `reloadData` before calling the update block, which renders whatever changes you plan to make during the update block poisonous to the collection view bookkeeping.

If you plan to have batch updates applied to the view before it's been properly laid out (like from a notification handler in a rapidly changing data model environment for instance), you need to make sure that in `viewWillAppear:` that you call `layoutIfNeeded` on the collection view.  This will prevent the collection view from reloading in the call to `performBatchUpdates:`.

We discovered this behavior by putting a log in our collection view data source `numberOfSections` method and printed out this backtrace to see where it was called from:

```
2014-11-12 15:30:06.173 CVCrasher[66830:6387719] [CV] #sections stack: (
0   CVCrasher     0x000000010ba9122d -[MyViewController numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:] + 61
1   UIKit         0x000000010cfc2811 -[UICollectionViewData _updateItemCounts] + 147
2   UIKit         0x000000010cfc4a89 -[UICollectionViewData numberOfSections] + 22
3   UIKit         0x000000010cfaebae -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _getSizingInfos] + 348
4   UIKit         0x000000010cfafca9 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:] + 526
5   UIKit         0x000000010cfab51f -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout prepareLayout] + 257
6   UIKit         0x000000010cfc2a10 -[UICollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData] + 67
7   UIKit         0x000000010cfc30e9 -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 54
8   UIKit         0x000000010cf8b7b8 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 170
9   UIKit         0x000000010c9d1973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
10  QuartzCore    0x0000000110cf2de8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
11  QuartzCore    0x0000000110ce7a0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
12  UIKit         0x000000010c9c5847 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 611
13  UIKit         0x000000010cf9c7b7 -[UICollectionView performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 164
...
```

Here you can plainly see that the call to `performBatchUpdates:` is hitting the datasource and becoming consistent with the changed model *before* the updates are applied. When the block itself is then called, the collection view will throw an assert like I showed in the original question.

**tl;dr** - When UICollectionView needs layout, `performBatchUpdates:` effectively acts as a call to `reloadData` and will make the batch update block assert because of bad bookkeeping.  Call `layoutIfNeeded` in `viewWillAppear:` to avoid this behavior.

Comment: Do you mean call `layoutIfNeeded` in `viewWillAppear:` and call `performBatchUpdates:` later in `viewDidAppear:` ? So when call `performBatchUpdates:` in `viewDidAppear:`, the UICollectionView will check to find it do not need to do layout again and will not call `reloadData`?

Comment: This freaking bug just took more than a day to solve. Thanks for your answer, pointed me in the right direction. Doing `layoutIfNeeded` in `viewWillAppear` does not work for us because the updates begin even earlier - but doing a `layoutIfNeeded` right before our data model updates solves it! This should definitely be filed as a bug to Apple. If they decide to do `reloadData` instead of the batch updates, they must discard the batch update block to avoid inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour and not a bug. From the documentation on [`performBatchUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates):

> If the collection view's layout is not up to date before you call this method, a reload may occur. To avoid problems, you should update your data model inside the updates block or ensure the layout is updated before you call performBatchUpdates(_:completion:).